# flutter integration test with FlutterDrive how to do a long press

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I am trying to do a long-press with flutter drive integration test.

using

```
await driver.tap(longPressButtonFinder);
```

does not help, is there something better than that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Update

The [longPress](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetController/longPress.html) method has been added to the `WidgetTester` class

#### Original

`FlutterDriver` doesn't seem to have this method out of the box.

A workaround is to scroll with a 0 delta. That will lead the driver to do what effectively is a long press.

```dart
await driver.scroll(target, 0, 0, Duration(milliseconds: 400));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately driver is a FlutterDriver and there is no longPress or is there a way to create the WidgetTester for integration test?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit more of your code? The widget tester should be available inside your test methods.

Comment: @ThomasFrick I dug around a bit and updated my answer.

Comment: @ThomasFrick FlutterDriver is pretty dumb. It's for runtime testing and performance profiling.
WidgetTester is for instant testing in your IDE, without deploying a real build into your device, and it has much more capabillities.

Comment: As of Flutter 2 you can now long press. Look at the answer underneath

Answer (score 1):

Starting with **Flutter 2** there is the following method available within WidgetTester class.

[longPress](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetController/longPress.html)

This is more explained in the above link.